# Why is the PagingNavigator not generating the urls?

Tags: wicket

I have a problem with PagingNavigator in Wicket and I don't understand why am I having it. Here is the thing, I wanted to use a PagingNavigator with a Dataview

```
dataView = new DataView("pageableTicketsList", provider){
    protected void populateItem(final Item item) {
       //Somes codes here
    };
navigator = new PagingNavigator("navigator", dataView);
dataView.setItemsPerPage(30);
addOrReplace(dataView);
addOrReplace(navigator);
```

In the html file, I simply have :

```
<wicket:enclosure child="navigator">     
 <div class="navigator">
         <span wicket:id="navigator" ></span>
    </div>     
</wicket:enclosure>
```

When I test in a webBrowser, in fact, I have the pages number shown as :

<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 > >>

BUT any of them are clickable.

I saw in FireBug that the urls are not properly generated like this :

```
<a href="?wicket:interface=:13:mypage:navigator:navigation:0:pageLink:4:ILinkListener::"><span>1</span>
</a>
```

Instead, I'm just having

```
<span>1</span>
```

I don't get it, what am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code of my provider

```
public class MyProvider implements IDataProvider {

    private List<Ticket> ticketsList;

    public MyProvider(TicketService ticketService // and some paramaters){
            ticketsList = ticketService.getListBy(//the parameters);
    }

    public Iterator iterator(int first, int count) {
    return ticketsList.subList(first, first + count).iterator();
    }

    public IModel model(final Object object) {
            return new LoadableDetachableModel() {
            @Override
                protected Object load() {
               return (Ticket)object;
            }};
    }

    public int size() {
    return ticketsList.size();
    }

    public void detach() {

    }

    public List<Ticket> getTicketsList() {
    return ticketsList;
    }

    public void setTicketsList(List<ListTicketsExtranetView> ticketsList) {
    this.ticketsList = ticketsList;
    }
}
```

The method `size()` returns the right value and `navigator.isEnabled()` returns true

Well, after a whole day of digging, I finally found out where my problem came from :
I have a `WebMarkupContainer` that was added to my page, if I remove that `WebMarkupContainer`, the `PagingNavigator` works fine. There is no dependencies beetween the 2 of them though, I use the `WebMarkupContainer` to show a message if a list of Tickets is empty or not.
So WHY is the `WebMarkupContainer` having influence on the `PagingNavigator` ?

Comment: Are you using Ajax? If so, did you add the `PagingNavigator` to the request target?

Comment: About the WebMarkupContainer: hard to tell without seeing more of the code. Can you pride some more?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code of your class that implements `IDataProvider`, e.g. `SortableDataProvider`? If the `size()` method isn't returning the right value, you might encounter the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. Did you set anything to disabled with

> setEnabled(false);

That has effect on components below that in the hierarchy. If that does not make a difference, try posting some more code.

Comment: I checked and I found any `navigator.setEnabled(false)` but thanks, anyway, I added  `navigator.setEnabled(true)` but nothing changed T_T.